# Unable to find index for $geoNear query even when index was created

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have following schema where I have an 2d-index on geo coordinates.

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var LocationSchema = new Schema ({
    geo: {
        type: [Number],
        required: true,
        index: "2dsphere"
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Location", LocationSchema);
```

I want to find new locations:

```
Location.find({
    geo: {
        $nearSphere: [req.query.lat, req.query.lng],
        $maxDistance: maxDistance
    }
}, function(err, events) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).json(err);
    }
    res.status(200).json(events);
});
```

The index seems to be created:

```
> db.system.indexes.find();
{ "v" : 1, "key" : { "geo" : "2dsphere" }, "name" : "geo_2dsphere", "ns" : "dev.events", "background" : true, "safe" : null, "2dsphereIndexVersion" : 2 }
```

Although I am creating an index here I get the following error when I want to find nearby locations:

```
{ [MongoError: Unable to execute query: error processing query: ns=dev.locations limit=1000 skip=0
Tree: GEONEAR  field=loc maxdist=0.156961 isNearSphere=0
Sort: {}
Proj: {}
planner returned error: unable to find index for $geoNear query]
name: 'MongoError',
message: 'Unable to execute query: error processing query: ns=dev.locations limit=1000 skip=0\nTree: GEONEAR  field=loc maxdist=0.156961 isNearSphere=0\nSort: {}\nProj: {}\n planner returned error: unable to find index for $geoNear query',
'$err': 'Unable to execute query: error processing query: ns=dev.locations limit=1000 skip=0\nTree: GEONEAR  field=loc maxdist=0.156961 isNearSphere=0\nSort: {}\nProj: {}\n planner returned error: unable to find index for $geoNear query',
code: 17007 }
```

Answer (score 7):

From [Mongo Docs](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/tutorial/query-a-2dsphere-index/) Mongo uses [longitude, latitude], here you are using the reverse.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issue after migrating parse database to AWS.
I got the issue solved by

```
db.prod.createIndex({ "location": "2d" })
```

Where prod is my collection name and location is name of column which stores geo location (GeoPoint)

Discussion related &geoNear can be found at [geo location issue(github)](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/issues/1592)

Answer (score 0):

You have defined "geo" in your location schema and you are finding using

```
loc : {
         $nearSphere: [req.query.lat, req.query.lng],
         $maxDistance: maxDistance
      }
```

Change it to

```
geo : {
         $nearSphere: [req.query.lat, req.query.lng],
         $maxDistance: maxDistance
      }
```

Comment: Hi, this was not the issue. Still get the same error.

Comment: You've give first longitude then latitude as per mongodb queries $nearSphere: [req.query.lng, req.query.lat]. Hope it will works

Answer (score 0):

make sure your field name in query matches name in the schema. For my this error came, because my schema had 'loc' and query was searching for 'lastLocation'.

```
 var mongoQuery = User.find({
                lastLocation: {
                    $near: coordinates,
                    $maxDistance: maxDistance
                }
            }).limit(limit);

var UserSchema   = new mongoose.Schema({
    //...
    lastLocation: {
        type: [Number],
        index: '2d'
    }
});
```